# perl: precedence of array operations

Tags: arrays, perl, operator-precedence

I'm having some trouble wrapping my head around perl's order of operations. I have the following:

```
>> my $n = 2;
>> my @arr = (1,2,3,4);
>> print $n/scalar @arr * 100;
0.005
```

But adding parens:

```
>> my $n = 2;
>> my @arr = (1,2,3,4);
>> print $n/(scalar @arr) * 100;
50
```

Looking at the [order of operations](https://www.washington.edu/perl5man/pod/perlop.html), it seems as though the first thing that should happen are list operations.  In this case, the first one encountered would be `scalar @arr`, which should return 4.  The resulting expression should be `print $n/4 * 100`, which would follow a standard order of operations and produce `50`.

But instead, I assume what is happening is it is performing `@arr * 100` first, which produces the scalar value `400`, then executed `scalar 400`, which produces `400`, then executes `$n/400`, giving `0.005`.

If the latter is what is happening, then my question is where does `scalar` fall in the order of operations. If something else is going on, then my question is, well, what?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can see how Perl parses the code by running it through [B::Deparse](http://p3rl.org/B::Deparse) with `-p`:

```
perl -MO=Deparse,-p script.pl
```

I tried 3 different ways:

```
print $n/scalar @arr * 100;
print $n/(scalar @arr) * 100;
print $n/@arr * 100;
```

This was the output:

```
print(($n / scalar((@arr * 100))));                                                                                                         
print((($n / scalar(@arr)) * 100));                                                                                                         
print((($n / @arr) * 100));
```

`*` is higher than the "named unary operators" (where [scalar](http://p3rl.org/scalar) belongs, check the link) in the precedence table in [perlop](http://p3rl.org/perlop).

Comment: so what does "Terms and list operators (leftward)" mean?

Comment: [Leftward](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Terms-and-List-Operators-(Leftward)), [Rightward](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#List-Operators-(Rightward)).

Answer (score 1):

From perlop documentation

> In the absence of parentheses, the precedence of list operators such
> as print, sort, or chmod is either very high or very low depending on
> whether you are looking at the left side or the right side of the
> operator. For example, in
>
> ```
>    @ary = (1, 3, sort 4, 2);
>    print @ary;        # prints 1324
> ```
>
> the commas on the right of the sort are evaluated before the sort, but the commas on the left are evaluated after. In other words, list operators tend to gobble up all the arguments that follow them, and then act like a simple TERM with regard to the preceding expression.

And `*` operator has a higher precedence `7.` than named unary operator `10.`

so in `scalar @arr * 100` `*` has higher precedence.

Comment: I don't follow. So `scalar` can have different precedence based on whether it's to the left or the right? Can you call it from the right? I'm totally lost.

Comment: Maybe the meaning is not clear, maybe it's about `list operators` `leftward` `1.` but `rightward` `21.`

Comment: yes, but I still don't follow. What does `leftward` and `rightward` refer to? Is there some postfix version of `scalar` or something?

Comment: from the example the sort takes the list on the right but the result is also a list so appened with list operator

Comment: @ewok, Added the rest of the sentence. It should make more sense now.

Comment: While `scalar` is a named list operator, it's more precisely a named unary operator, so it's actually at precedence 10 (not 21)